# Express.js: Express global error handler not working, exception still crash the application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I added an express global error handler at the last few lines of app.js, however a thrown exception in a controller still crashed the application.

identity.controller.js

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
exports.identifyUser = async (req, res) => {
    throw new createError(404, 'Test');
}
```

app.js

```
// Configure routes
routes.register(app);

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500).json(response.error(err.status || 500));
});

module.exports = app;
```

When `identifyUser` was called, I expect an error response 500 from express. However, an exception was uncaught and killed my application.

```
NotFoundError: Test
    at exports.identifyUser (C:\Users\......\src\api\controllers\identity.controller.js:9:11)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at C:\Users\......\src\api\middlewares\authUser.js:30:16
    at C:\Users\......\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:223:12
    at getSecret (C:\Users\......\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:90:14)
    at module.exports [as verify] (C:\Users\......\node_modules\jsonwebtoken\verify.js:94:10)
    at C:\Users\......\src\api\middlewares\authUser.js:19:16
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
    at router (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
    at C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\......\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)

Node.js v18.7.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I'm running Node.js v18.7.0 with Express 4.18.1 on Windows 11.

Answer (score 1):

From the Express documentation:

> For errors returned from asynchronous functions invoked by route handlers and middleware, you must pass them to the next() function, where Express will catch and process them.

Try replace

```
exports.identifyUser = async (req, res) => {
    throw new createError(404, 'Test');
}
```

by

```
exports.identifyUser = async (req, res, next) => {
    next(new createError(404, 'Test'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The global error handler from Express will not catch any error in your application, you still have to do it yourself with a try/catch block then call the `next` function with your error as parameter.

```
const createError = require('http-errors');

exports.identifyUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    throw new createError(404, 'Test');
  } catch(err) {
    next(err);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need http-errors as long as you're using express, you can just throw new Error.

Try This:

```
exports.identifyUser = async (request, response, next) => {
    try {
        throw new Error (404, 'Test'));
    } catch {
        next (Error);
    }
}
```